# Write to Public calendar in 365 from SQL Server 2016

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

We are hoping to write to a public calendar within our Office 365 tenant the operating hours of our business. The hours are originated within SQL Server (now updated to 2016). I am hoping we can do this with the Graph API but haven't seen explicit docs on PUT endpoints for the shared calendar objects.

Are these resources readily available or is this a roadblock issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is work in progress, and we will update this thread when access to calendars other than the signed-in user's calendars is available through Microsoft Graph.

Comment: What about utilizing signed in administrator access to a public calendar?